# How would I show the latest registered users with php and sql

Tags: php

I just wondering if there is any way could display the latest users by getting it from the database and displaying the most recent registrations the script i am using is written in php and mysql database Thanks

Comment: Do you store the date/time the user registers at? If so, this should be trivial. However, as we're not psychic we don't know what your database schemas look like. (You might want to update your question and tell us.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [order by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html) clause to sort based on the registration date (if you're saving it in your database.

You can also only return a certain number of results with the [limit](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm) function.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **auto_increment** for **user_id** field in user table, you might get the latest registered user by select the last inserted record (LIMIT 1) order by **user_id** from the DB.

Anyway, the best way to deal with this is to add **registration_date** field to the table as the two answers above said.